# How to remove the alerts of dependabot under security tab in github

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKyo7.png) In github under the security tab there is a Dependabot column .
There are more security alerts in that column. In order to fix the alerts

we need to increase the version of packages listed in package-lock.json file. but my seniors suggested not to commit these changes into github. Anyone having idea to fix this alerts issue?

Comment: You mean, not submit the changes to the `package-lock.json`? Is that not versioned? Which would be okay for a library. But in a project you should always commit your lock files!

Comment: I'm not clear. Could you suggest me any solution to fix this issues.
I have attached the screenshot in description.

Comment: Well, the proper way to "get rid of the alerts" is to update your dependencies to their respective newest possible version. This would be stored in the lock file then. But I'm not quite sure why your seniors said, that you should not commit them to GitHub. Because then GitHub won't know about the new version and still show the alerts. It seems from your screenshot that there already some pull requests (#22, #112, ...) open to address the problem. Won't they be merged?

Comment: The CI status of PR are failed.I'm working on to fix this issues.